# how to do join of two files conditioned by two columns, by using join command and awk script

Tags: unix, join, awk

I would like to discard rows of one file conditioned by the other file, with the condition is set by the two columns they shared. This means I want to discard the rows of file_1, with the same values in the two common columns (columns 2 and 3) shared in the other file (file_2).

I want to use `join` command to do that, But, I failed.

```
# The command I used:
join -j 2 -j 3 -a 2 file_2.txt file_1.txt
```

Could you point me the errors and help me to correct it? And also, I want to know how to do this job by using Awk script.

```
# the two files are **tab-delimited**, and the key fields used to join are **column 2** and **column 3** in  
# these two files. 
**# file_1.txt**

AL3C3P1-4 1 1 T T 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 2 C A 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 3 A A 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 4 C C 1 2 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 5 T T 2 3 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 6 T T 2 5 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 7 T T 2 6 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 8 C C 3 9 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 9 A A 3 8 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 10 C - 3 10 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 11 T T 6 11 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 12 T - 6 11 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 13 C - 8 13 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 14 T - 10 15 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 15 G G 12 15 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 16 G G 12 16 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 17 A A 14 18 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 18 T T 14 19 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 19 G G 14 18 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 20 C C 14 22 1 1

**# file_2.txt**
AL3C3P1-4 1 1 T T 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 2 C A 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 3 A A 1 1 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 4 C C 1 2 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 10 C - 3 10 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 11 T T 6 11 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 12 T - 6 11 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 13 C - 8 13 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 14 T - 10 15 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 15 G G 12 15 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 16 G G 12 16 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 17 A A 14 18 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 18 T T 14 19 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 19 G G 14 18 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 20 C C 14 22 1 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2$3];next} (!($2$3 in a))' file2 file1
AL3C3P1-4 1 5 T T 2 3 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 6 T T 2 5 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 7 T T 2 6 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 8 C C 3 9 1 1
AL3C3P1-4 1 9 A A 3 8 1 1
```

Comment: That is so cool and powerful solution by awk. Thanks a lot ghostdog74.

Comment: @jianfeng.mao : Now you need to *thank* ghostdog74 by clicking on the up arrow at the top left of his answer, and if this exactly the solution you need, click in the middle of the 0 (or 1), also at the top left. Then you will be giving him the points he has earned.

Comment: sorry I need 15 reputation to do that. I tried. But, I can not dot that. I will do that, after I have enough reputation.

Comment: could anyone give me any directions on how to do this job by join command. I really want to know that.

Comment: @jianfeng.mao: "Thanks a lot" is best expressed [by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).